# Enabling whole module optimization in AppCode?

Tags: appcode

How can I enable whole module optimization in AppCode?

In XCode 7, whole module optimization can be enabled in the build settings. I'm looking for the equivalent settings menu in AppCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File->Project Settings

Choose project in left pane upper and lower sections

Build Settings->User-Defined Settings->SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL->Enter `-Owholemodule`